# printing rank of a player and his(her) neighbors

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

There is a table which stored highest score of every game player:

```
select * from TMP_TABLE
```

which results:

```
USERID     SCORE
---------- -----------
aaa         10
bbb         30
ccc         50
ddd         90
eee         80
fff         50
ggg         20
hhh         40
iii         50

(9 row(s) affected)
```

Ok, now I want to show rank of every player:

```
select *,r=rank() over(order by score desc) from TMP_TABLE
```

which results

```
USERID     SCORE       r
---------- ----------- --------------------
ddd        90          1
eee        80          2
fff        50          3
ccc        50          3
iii        50          3
hhh        40          6
bbb        30          7
ggg        20          8
aaa        10          9

(9 row(s) affected)
```

Now I want to print rank of user 'bbb' and his(her) neighboring players' name and score, like this:

```
USERID     SCORE       r
---------- ----------- --------------------
hhh        40          6
bbb        30          7
ggg        20          8
(3 row(s) affected)
```

However, I cannot figure out which query statement shows this result. Of course, processing performance should be considered.
Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: what `RDBMS` you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your `RDBMS` supports `Common Table Expression`, here's my first try,

```
WITH ranking AS
(
  SELECT *,
         RANK() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC) userRank
  FROM   TableName  
)
SELECT *
FROM   ranking
WHERE  userRank BETWEEN
        (SELECT userRank - 1 FROM ranking WHERE userID = 'bbb') AND
        (SELECT userRank + 1 FROM ranking WHERE userID = 'bbb')
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e804d/6)

Answer (score 1):

One more option

```
;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT *,
         RANK() OVER(ORDER BY score DESC) AS r,
         CASE WHEN USERID = 'bbb' THEN RANK() OVER(ORDER BY score DESC) - 1 END AS bRank,
         CASE WHEN USERID = 'bbb' THEN RANK() OVER(ORDER BY score DESC) + 1 END AS eRank
  FROM dbo.TMP_TABLE
  )
  SELECT USERID, SCORE, r
  FROM cte c
  WHERE USERID = 'bbb' OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cte WHERE c.r BETWEEN bRank AND eRank)
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3f12a/1/0)

It will be possible to use the best way DENSE_RANK when hhh and bbb equals

Demo with DENSE_RANK on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1f30e/2/0)